# Writing a method to accept interface type instead of class type

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am trying to create some classes that implement a particular interface (in this case, `XYPlottable`) and a method that can handle any class implementing that interface.

So far I have the following (that works):

```
public interface XYPlottable {
    public Number getXCoordinate();
    public Number getYCoordinate();
    public Number getCoordinate(String fieldName);
}

public class A implements XYPlottable {
//Implements the above interface properly
...
}

public class B implements XYPlottable {
//Implements the above interface properly
...
}
```

This works fine. I also have a method to try and plot anything that's XYPlottable:

```
public static Frame createPlot(String title, String xAxisLabel, String yAxisLabel,
                               List<XYPlottable> points, boolean fitLine) {
```

So I attempt to go use it with one of the above concrete classes and it complains about having incompatible types:

```
List<A> values = _controller.getValues(tripName);
XYPlotter.createPlot("Plot A", "B", "C", values, false);
```

Here's the exact error:

```
incompatible types
  required: java.util.List<XYPlottable>
  found:    java.util.List<A>
```

I hoping I'm just having a moment and missing something really obvious, but maybe I'm having a misunderstanding of how I should be using interfaces.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Method declaration like following should work -

```
public static Frame createPlot(String title, String xAxisLabel, String yAxisLabel,
                               List<? extends XYPlottable> points, boolean fitLine) {
```

Note the change in the parameter `List<XYPlottable>` to `List<? extends XYPlottable>` - This is called as wildcards. 
Read more about generic wildcards [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: Is generics required in this case or could you just use the interface (XYPlottable) as the list type?

Comment: @Strawberry - It's altogether different question :) .. would you like to post it? will get a good answers ;)

Comment: Cool. This seems to work great. I am a little confused as to why the interface type itself cannot just be used, but it must just mean I have to read more about generics since my basic understanding doesn't seem to be sufficient anymore.

Comment: @Doug Swain - Generics is little confusing.. [This](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) is really good link to start with.

Comment: Posted a question relating to using a straight interface vs a generic-wildcard interface [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771474/use-of-generic-wildcard-instead-of-interface).

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
List<? extends XYPlottable>
```

in the method declaration.

Generics in Java can be confusing.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using the concrete type `A` in your list of values. This should be a list of `XYPlottables` e.g

```
List<XYPlottable> value = _controller.getValues(tripName)
```

Comment: I tried this before and it wasn't working. I believe the reason is because the method of the _controller object instance returns a List of a concrete type and so it wouldn't automatically cast.

Comment: Oh okay. I'll leave my dud answer for others to see :)