# Use of generic wildcard instead of interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, wildcard

If you wanted to store an array of objects of type `MyInterface`, are the following both acceptable and if so when would you use the second form over the first?

i) Using only an interface:-

```
List<MyInterface> mylist = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
```

ii) Using a generic wildcard:-

```
List<? extends MyInterface> mylist = new ArrayList<? extends MyInterface>();
```

Edit:

As the answers so far have pointed out, number ii won't compile. What is the difference between i and a case iii where :-

iii) Using a generic wildcard only in the reference:-

```
List<? extends MyInterface> mylist = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Second one won't compile. Imagine:

```
A implements MyInterface
B implements MyInterface
```

Then the following would match your second expression, but won't compile:

```
// incorrect
List<A> mylist = new ArrayList<B>();
```

**Correction: Wrong one too**:

```
List<? extends MyInterface> mylist = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
```

It is right in a sense it does compile, but you cannot add any subclasses of MyInterface to it. Confusing, but correct -- after I read the explanation. Same reason: wildcard can be viewed for example as:

```
// I know this is not compileable; this is internal compiler "thinking".
// Read it as "somewhere someone may instantiate an ArrayList<A> and pass 
// it down to us; but we cannot accept it as something that could be 
// potentially used as List<B>"
List<A> mylist = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
```

So this won't work:

```
mylist.add(b);
```

and vice versa. Compiler refuses to do those potentially incorrect operations.

The option which allows you to add any subclass of MyInterface to mylist is:

```
List<MyInterface> mylist = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
```

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to store the ojects of type `MyInterface` the better (and compilable) approach would be -

> ```
> List<MyInterface> mylist = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
> ```

But if you would like to use in the method parameter then you can use option 2 (bounded wildcard type) for API flexibility.

> ```
> public void someMethod(List<? extends MyInterface> myInterfaces);
> ```

**EDIT:**
The above code will give the more flexibility API because Generic types are *invariant*, so if you have -

```
public class A implements MyInterface {
  // some implementation 
}
```

and if `someMethod` has a parameter type `List<MyInterface>` then it won't be able to take the `List<A>`, this forces API users to create `List` with type `MyInterface` on the other side - 
  `List<? extends MyInterface>` will allow to pass `List<A>` to `someMethod`.. client usually has a `List<ActualObject>` so it's more flexible to provide a parameter which will take any implementation of `MyInterface`

At the same time do **not** use wildcard types as return types like

> ```
> public List<? extends MyInterface> someMethod();
> ```

If the user of a class has to think about wildcard types, there is probably something wrong with the class’s API.

Comment: In your `someMethod` example why wouldn't you just use `List<MyInterface>` instead?

Comment: Try to use this API first. Call it with an actual class. There might be some surprises. ;)

Answer (score 5):

`List<? extends MyInterface>` means **a list of some subtype of `MyInterface`, but we don't know which subtype.**

Since we don't know which subtype is used actually, we can't put any object in it (as we can't ensure that it is an element of this subtype).

We can take objects out of such a list, and know that it is an object implementing `MyInterface`, but nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the second will not compile. You can't instantiate a type parameter with another type parameter with bounds.

Answer (score 0):

use exact and complete type info in implementations.

```
ArrayList<MyInterface> mylist = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
```